# Styling the align attribute in css for images

Tags: css, image, alignment

if you have an image that still sues the align feature, such that `<img src="x" align="left" />` how would you style that so you can give padding for text on the right side? in css?

Answer (score 2):

First, why do you have HTML with the align tag? Assuming you are working with some hideously old code that can't be changed, a selector like:

```
img[align='left'] {
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Will do the job.

If you just added the align tag, take it out, and add a class to deal with this.

Comment: In 12 minutes I can accept this - thank you. And I didn't - WordPress did ... I could use jquery to remove the attribute of all images.

Answer (score 0):

my code would be like so:

```
img{margin-right:10px; /*10px is an example value, set your own*/}
/*the following selector will only work for images with align="left" set*/
img[align="left"]{margin-right:10px;}
```